Cannot build native binaries in project generated with Kotlin Multiplatform Wizard
I generated a Desktop multiplatform project with https://kmp.jetbrains.com/
I'm trying to build native binary, I added these to build.gradle.ks
    val nativeTarget = linuxX64("native")
    nativeTarget.apply {
        binaries {
            executable {
                entryPoint = "main"
            }
        }
    }

When syncing after file change I get this error:
:composeApp:nativeMain: Could not resolve org.jetbrains.compose.foundation:foundation:1.6.0.
Required by:
    project :composeApp

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html


You can find the code here https://github.com/radumarias/Kotlin-Multiplatform-Wizard-Desktop/blob/main/composeApp/build.gradle.kts#L12
There are several repos added as you can see here https://github.com/radumarias/Kotlin-Multiplatform-Wizard-Desktop/blob/main/settings.gradle.kts#L5
I found this
compose-plugin = "1.6.0"

here https://github.com/radumarias/Kotlin-Multiplatform-Wizard-Desktop/blob/main/gradle/libs.versions.toml#L3C1-L3C25
I tried with other versions too, getting error for new version also.
How can I build the native binary? Or at least how can I create a jar that I can run with java -jar?
Tried to build native binary, expecting to work.
